# SQL replace value with the name of its respective column

Tags: sql

I am trying to replace the value of a cell which contains 'X' with the name of its column.

Example:

Turning this sql table:

[image: input]

into this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression for each column.

```
select case when column1 = 'X' then 'Column1' else <whatever> end as column1,
       case when column2 = 'X' then 'Column2' else <whatever> end as column2,
...
       case when column1340 = 'X' then 'Column1340' else <whatever> end as column1340
from tablename
```

If you simply want NULL instead of whatever, you can skip the `else <whatever>` part.

Comment: I have a huge set of columns I can't enter each and every one of them into the sql request, and it wouldn't be very adaptive either.

Comment: With 1340 columns you are in trouble... Either use dynamic sql, or re-design the db.

Answer (score 0):

For 1,300 columns, I would go Dynamic SQL

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select @SQL = @SQL+coalesce(';Update ['+Table_Name+'] Set ['+Column_Name+']='''+Column_Name+''' where ['+Column_Name+']=''X''' ,'')
  From (Select Table_Name,Column_Name From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where Table_Name='SomeTable') A
Print @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

;Update [SomeTable] Set [column1]='column1' where [column1]='X';Update [SomeTable] Set [column2]='column2' where [column2]='X';Update [SomeTable] Set [column3]='column3' where [column3]='X'

Comment: That sounds nice however I will very unfortunately have to do it in Access so I don't know if Dynamic SQL will be possible.

Comment: Sorry,I'm SQL Server centric.  When I saw the tag SQL I just assumed.